# typescript define class with dynamic unknown props

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a definition file for the package `vform`

```
  class Form {
    constructor (data?: { [filed: string]: string })
    busy: boolean
    successful: boolean
    errors: Errors
    get(url: string): Promise<any>
    post(url: string): Promise<any>
    patch(url: string): Promise<any>
    put(url: string): Promise<any>
    delete(url: string): Promise<any>
    clear(): void
    reset(): void
    fill(data: { [filed: string]: string }): void
  }

  export default Form
```

The main constructor permits to access field values initialized during object creation, for example:

```
const f = new Form({ foo: 'abc' })
f.foo // return 'abc' value
```

So I tried to define a dynamic prop in the class like that (fields are always string):

```
  class Form {
    [...]
    [field: string]: string
  }
```

But it's not working and I get `'filed' is not defined.` error, also the other fields become invalid cause string type is not assignable.

What's the correct way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an index signature to get this behavior because it would require that every single member be a `string`, including the properties and methods.  There is currently no way to support "rest" or "default" index signatures that apply only to properties not explicitly mentioned.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#17687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867) for the relevant feature request.

Instead you would be better off using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to say that the `Form` constructor produces a value assignable to `T`, the same type that was passed into the constructor.

This is actually much easier to accomplish as a set of declarations that apply to an existing JavaScript library than it is to write the same library in TypeScript. You can't write `class Foo<T> implements T {}` because you are only allowed to extend/implement types whose members are statically known at compiler time.  You instead need to refer to the [static side and instance side of your class explicitly as interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes), as is sometimes done in the standard TypeScript library to represent built-in JavaScript classes [such as `Array`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b1f86eca3e304aa5a7f6b236dab656978e2e405a/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1220-L1424).

Here's how I might write `Form`:

```
interface FormConstructor {
    new <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(data?: T): Form<T>;
}
interface BaseForm {
    busy: boolean
    successful: boolean
    // errors: Errors 
    get(url: string): Promise<any>
    post(url: string): Promise<any>
    patch(url: string): Promise<any>
    put(url: string): Promise<any>
    delete(url: string): Promise<any>
    clear(): void
    reset(): void
    fill(data: { [filed: string]: string }): void
}
type Form<T> = BaseForm & T;
declare const Form: FormConstructor;
```

This will behave very much like a `class`.  There is a value named `Form` whose type is `FormConstructor`.  When you call `new Form(data)` when `data` is of type `T`, it will produce a value of type `Form<T>`, which is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the `BaseForm` with no extra properties and `T`, the type of `data`.

If you had to write that in TypeScript also it would require [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler that your value named `Form` actually conforms to `FormConstructor`, since again, the compiler will not accept that a `class` can implement a generic type with unknown keys.  Luckily we don't have to implement anything ourselves.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const f = new Form({ foo: 'abc' });
// const f: Form<{ foo: string; }>
f.foo.toUpperCase(); // okay
f.clear(); // okay
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsDC6QDOYUArgmJsgN4CwAUMo8iBAO7IA8AKshAB6QQAEwLIAShASYhHANYQAnuhjIuAGmREooAOYA+PQAohcMHAD8ALlUBKaxmzc9AbnoBfeqEixEKAEJwBBAOWNT0TMgARiQECtaR6OgANhBwIOFMBGRIBAQwJEnxiSlpGYwA9OW8UFCYBNYAojV1yGXIOhBghiRQhZrEunbIAAq1WMBBHGkKem0ADuhE3b3WWoPWo+jjk9OzDExzpggAFst9ayA6Q5vbEFMgM-MkXT3nA5fXYxN3u21CEClIGdVu8rhsvjsHnsIggSlBDEMAG7oYBCNpQCBBLpIlFo-aMGDAJJJYymODWKjIADahJSQhB2kuAF0GbpkG4caj3PQwAo5igQk5kABeZABIIhZAAMlUrjo-1hcAxyCkhDAaEwWHsmrwatI5EwcvoqqIyBUopY7BChkpMES1gA5HBIggHeybHLKir8KaYNrHLb7f1GTpnOy9jAAHR29CRigAVTm-KgOECEARYa96FkcAU9CjsNS8I9yCzObzdCAA)

Comment: Works great, also thanks for explanation!